# How To Exclude Some Files From Checking Operations

Tags: java, formatting, code-formatting, checkstyle

I am using checkstyle plugin to format my code and I need to exclude some java classes from checking operations. To do that, I wrote the code below:

```
<module name="BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter">
    <property name="fileNamePattern" value="src/main/java/package1/*.java"/>
</module>

<module name="BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter">
    <property name="fileNamePattern" value="src/main/java/package2/*.java"/>
</module>
```

I tried to exclude all classes in 2 different packages. But the code does not works unfortunately. I also tried as below:

```
<module name="BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter">
    <property name="fileNamePattern" value="src/main/java/package1/*.java"/>
    <property name="fileNamePattern" value="src/main/java/package2/*.java"/>
</module>
```

But this did not worked as well. The checkstyle plugin again checks all classes. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution after long tries. My format for giving a path was wrong. Correct format should be like this one:

```
    <module name="BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter">
    <property name="fileNamePattern" value="[/\\]src[/\\]main[/\\]java[/\\]package1"/>
    </module>

    <module name="BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter">
        <property name="fileNamePattern" value="[/\\]src[/\\]main[/\\]java[/\\]package2"/>
    </module>
```

If we wanna give more than one package to ignore, this is the way we should do. Giving two property with same name does not work. Hope this helps to others.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was `fileNamePattern` is treated as regex, so wildcard in `package1/*.java` would not match class name letters, but will be a quantifier for `/`.

Also, let's consider exclusion logic code in checkstyle(as of 10.09.2023):

```
public boolean accept(String uri) {
    return fileNamePattern == null || !fileNamePattern.matcher(uri).find();
}
```

Since it uses `find`, not `match`, common path can be omitted, and you can use regex `or` expression, so your xml may be stripped to

```
<module name="BeforeExecutionExclusionFileFilter">
    <property name="fileNamePattern" value="package1|package2"/>
</module>
```